# Floating divs layout coming out incorrectly

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I would like to divide the content rendered in the default MVC3 layout like this

```
<div id="main">
            <div id="left">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>    
             <div id="right">
             Feeds  here!
             </div>

        </div>
```

but it becomes like this
[image: wrong layout]
Here are parts in the CSS I fixed

```
#main #left
{
    float:left; 
}

#main #right
{
    position:fixed;
    padding-right:50px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:left;
}

#main {
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
    background-color:Black;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    clear:both;    

    color:White;
}
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: THe dark band should stick with the white band, the right column for feeds should fit inside the main area.

Comment: Well, when it's `position: fixed` it doesn't take up space. Make it fixed-width and change the right margin on `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about swapping the right div above the left in the HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="right">
        Feeds  here!
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Then for the css:

```
#main #left
{
}

#main #right
{
    float:right;
    padding-right:50px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now but when I resize the browser, the feed area goes out of the main content area. How can I stick its right side to the right side of the main content ?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour on the copy I have. Do you have other css in there that could be having an effect on those divs? Like does main or left have a static width it's getting from somewhere maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#main #left
{
    float:left; 
    width:600px;
}

#main #right
{
    padding-right:50px;
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
    float:right;
}
```

**Edited:** use your own widths to fit your design.